# How to add multiple arrow in bblock using tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: This is exactly what I want to make]I need to make a diagram having different transmitting antenna at left side and a receiver block at right side. For receiver I need multiple antennas. I am able get one antenna how to get more then one?

Secondly I want dashed line from antenna of coordinate `(0,-1.5)` to `(0,3)`.
The code I wrote is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cite}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{t1enc}
%\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{ellipsis}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\tikzset{block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle,
                  minimum height=16em, minimum width=2cm},
        input/.style = {coordinate},
        output/.style = {coordinate},
        pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,t,black}}
    }


\begin{document}

% Radius of regular polygons
\newdimen\R
\R=0.8cm

\begin{tikzpicture}



%####################################################################    

%####################  BASE STATIONS
\node (an1) at ($(0,0)$) {\includegraphics[scale=0.010]{bs.eps}};

\node (an2) at ($(0,-0.5)$) {\includegraphics[scale=.010]{bs.eps}};

\node (an2) at ($(0,0.5)$) {\includegraphics[scale=.010]{bs.eps}};
\node (an2) at ($(0,1)$) {\includegraphics[scale=.010]{bs.eps}};
\node (an2) at ($(0,-3)$) {\includegraphics[scale=.010]{bs.eps}};

\node[block,right = 10cm of an1](rx){receiver};
\node[antenna,xscale=-1] at (rx.west) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post an example image of what you want to do? And what is `bs.eps`? We don't have that graphic.

Comment: I have shared the image exactly what I need to make. bs.eps are the figures which I have form antennas at left side i.e. transmitter side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something to start. Two pics define the receiver and each transmitter antenna. 
A `foreach` loop draws arrows between transmitter and receiver. Probably will be better to forget `foreach` and draw each path individually to better place labels which are not shown here.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{
    tx/.pic={
        \node[isosceles triangle, draw, inner sep=0pt,  shape border rotate=90, minimum height=0.5cm] (-tx){};
            \draw ([shift={(.1,.1)}]-tx.north) arc[start angle=0, end angle=-180, radius=1mm];
            \draw ([shift={(.05,.1)}]-tx.north) arc[start angle=0, end angle=-180, radius=0.5mm];
    },
    rx/.pic={
        \node[minimum width=3cm, minimum height=5cm, draw] (-rx) {Receiver};
        \foreach \i in {1,2,3,5}
        \draw ([yshift=-\i cm+0.5cm]-rx.north west)--++(180:3mm) coordinate (-\i-rx)--++(90:3mm)--++(2mm,3mm)--++(-4mm,0mm)--++(2mm,-3mm);
        \path (-3-rx)--(-5-rx) node[pos=.25] {\vdots};
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pic (R) {rx};

\foreach \i in {1, 2, 3, 5}
{
    \pic (\i) at ([xshift=-3cm]R-\i-rx) {tx};
}

\path (3-tx)--(5-tx) node[pos=.25]{\vdots};

\foreach \i in {1,2,3,5}
    \foreach \j in {1,2,3,5}
        \draw[shorten >=2mm, shorten <=2mm,->] (\i-tx.north)--(R-\j-rx);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thanks How can we have dotted lines between second last and last?

Comment: And If I am running the code I am getting undefined control sequence for \pic. do I need to use any package for that?

Comment: @undefined If `\pic` is undefined, you probably need to update TiKZ to 3.00 version.

Comment: @undefined I've added some dots between antennas, is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes how to lable it? As I have labeled in example image. Can I do labeling in for loop?